# Why SVG exported image has a poor quality?

Tags: javascript, svg, vue.js, download, png

I rendered an SVG dynamically like this:

[image: SVG]

But when I downloaded it, it became like this:

[image: Downloaded]

I doubt it is due to my JavaScript code that messed it up but do not know why? I am a newbie to SVG so bear with me. Ideally I want to save it as a PNG file with no quality loss. Thank you so much ~!

```
    let svg = document.getElementById('graphSvg');

    // get svg source.
    let serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    let source = serializer.serializeToString(svg);

    // add name spaces.
    if (!source.match(/^<svg[^>]+xmlns="http\:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2000\/svg"/)) {
      source = source.replace(/^<svg/, '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"');
    }
    if (!source.match(/^<svg[^>]+"http\:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/1999\/xlink"/)) {
      source = source.replace(/^<svg/, '<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"');
    }

    // add xml declaration
    source = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>\r\n' + source;

    // convert svg source to URI data scheme.
    let url = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,'+encodeURIComponent(source);

    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = 'graph.svg';
    a.href = url;
    a.click();
```

Comment: The good looks of the SVG comes from CSS on the page?

Comment: @EmileBergeron : No. CSS is definitely taken into account. See some of the nodes are dark because its CSS has a background color.

Comment: Could you include a super simple SVG source as an example?

Comment: Include the SVG so we can see what was actually produced.

Comment: U guys are right. The effect is partially done by CSS and partially done by hard-coding

            `g.setNode(
          nodeKey,
          {
            label: curOpLabel ,
            shape: 'rect',
            style:  'opacity: 0.5; ' +
                    'rx: 10; ry: 10; ',

          }
        );` So here comes another question: Is there a way to also include the CSS in the exported PNG? Thanks!